# Neo4j-driver: Cannot read property 'driver' of undefined

Tags: javascript, neo4j, neo4j-driver

I pretty much copied the [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver) and adjusted the database query. I dont understand why the driver is not recognized?

Version:
   Node: v11.13.0 
   neo4j-driver: "^1.7.5"

I get the Error:

```
var driver = neo4j.v1.driver(
                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'driver' of undefined
```

My Code:

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;


var driver = neo4j.v1.driver(
    'bolt://localhost:7687',
    neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'Neo4j')
  )
  var session = driver.session()

session
  .run('MATCH (n:Person) return n', {
    //nameParam: 'Alice'
  })
  .subscribe({
    onNext: function(record) {
      console.log(record.get('n'))
    },
    onCompleted: function() {
      session.close()
    },
    onError: function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  })
```

Comment: Try with `var driver = neo4j.driver(` instead of  `var driver = neo4j.v1.driver(`

Comment: Ah im stuipid my Neo4j was not online anymore and you code change worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to do this:

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;

var driver = neo4j.driver(
...
```

Or, if for some reason you want to be able to explicitly specify the library version every time you use it, do this:

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver');

var driver = neo4j.v1.driver(
...
```

Answer (score 0):

their docs seem screwed up, I had the exact same problem.
remove the `v1` and it works. not sure if this defaults to a different version of the driver or something...

```
let config = require("./config")[env]

const uri = 'bolt://localhost:7687'
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver');
const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(config.username, config.password));
```

FWIW the way they define a config file is also broken. the node onboarding is pretty much a turn-off.